# Different assets per subdomain in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, assets, sprockets

So I'm in the process of building a Rails app that will serve different content based on the subdomain.

The app will always be live, and when we want to release a new brand (subdomain), say `newbrand.example.com`, we will package up assets for that brand using Sprockets and then dump them on S3 (subdomain is the subfolder name eg. `/brand/assets/...` and `/newbrand/assets/...`).

Assets and locales will be the only thing that changes per subdomain, I already have a clean solution for the locales (using the `i18n-active_record` gem) but I'm stumped at different assets per subdomain.

I have some custom code that hooks into Sprockets and packages up an assets dir and creates the necessary manifest file etc:

```
env = Sprockets::Environment.new

# manifest.compile fails when the below method isn't present
env.context_class.class_eval do
    def asset_path(path, options = {})
    end
end

%w[config fonts images javascripts stylesheets].each do |folder|
  Sprockets.append_path(File.join(Dir.pwd, 'assets', folder))
end

manifest = Sprockets::Manifest.new(env, File.join(Dir.pwd, 'compiled'))
assets = [%w[**/*.jpeg **/*.jpg **/*.svg **/*.png **/*.gif], ['**/*.js'], /(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.(css|js)$/]

manifest.compile(assets)
```

The idea is that in the background this precompiled assets folder will be sent to S3 via a separate task.

My problem is that I can't get Rails to look for the new assets when visiting on different subdomains.

The way I am switching the asset_host via subdomain is by doing the following:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
    "http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/#{request.subdomain}/"
}
```

So when I access `newbrand.example.com` I want it to load the assets from that subfolder on S3 and so on per brand. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your precompiled assets for each subdomain, are actually getting uploaded the subdomain's folder on S3?  Where are you "dumping" the assets to S3?

Comment: @BillDoughty yes they are, I'm connecting to my bucket via Cyberduck and checking that the subfolder exists and it does

Comment: Ok, have you tried logging YourApp::Application.config.action_controller.asset_host in one of your controller actions to make sure it's value is correct when you're on a subdomain?  I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @BillDoughty yes. It seems that the problem lies with the assets that live in the app. No matter how many different bunches of assets I create, the Rails app only looks for the assets that match the digests of the ones in the /assets folder